# Replace fragment don't show the whole fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I'm trying to replace view in FrameLayout with fragment. I want to make this like in Android guides, when I create fragment and it does't have enough space then it create new Activity. [example from android side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lA177.png)

I have problem with it. My fragment container is FrameLayout

```
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:layout_width="344dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>
```

fragment transaction suite my fragment to FrameLayout size. It makes that my fragment is not all visible (it's layout is bigger than FrameLayout size) I don't know why I have this problem. Here is my fragment transaction code (it makes when I click on Text View):

```
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    transaction.add(R.id.fragment, new FragmentPlan());
    transaction.commit();
```

my Fragment

```
    public class FragmentPlan extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plan, container, false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: just add `android:background="@android:color/white"` to the root view of the fragments

Comment: to fragment layout?

Comment: Yes, both fragments

Comment: It does't work :/

Comment: I have one activity and one fragment. In activity I have text view seek bar and frame layout. When I click on text view I want to show a fragment in frame layout. But it insert fragment into frame layout size don't create new activity

Comment: This is normal behavior, if you need to start new activity, then you have to create the activity, define it in `AndroidManifers.xml` and call `startActivity(new Intent(context, TargetActivityName.class));` and inside that activity, define your fragment.

Comment: so when can I make something like on android photo?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is running ok.

When you add/replace a viewGroup with a fragment, the fragment inherits the size from the viewGroup, for that reason, it is very small.

As I see, you can either increase the size of the frameLayout. Or like it was mentioned above int he comments, use an Intent to start a new Activity.